# Does Firebase limitToLast() take increasing longer as a child's record count grows?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a Firebase with a child named `lines`. `lines` contains about 500k records, each with eight key/value pairs.

When my app loads, it tries to grab the last 128 records in `lines` using the following:

```
fb = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/lines");
fb.limitToLast(128).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  // do something
});
```

I'm finding that my app's initial load time is getting slower and slower. The only thing that's changing is how many records there are under `lines`. Should I expect `limitToLast()` to take increasingly longer as the number of records under `lines` goes up? If so, I can try and cull the records over time, but I was under the impression that the `limitToLast()` query would only grab what is specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I expect limitToLast() to take increasing longer as the number of records under lines goes up?

Yes. Keep reading for why that is.

> If so, I can try and cull the records over time

That is indeed the recommended solution.

> but I was under the impression that the limitToLast() query would only grab what is specified.

It will only *send* the children matching your query to the client. But to know which children to send it needs to *consider* all of them. So while `limitToLast()` can be used to reduce *bandwidth*, they don't reduce "disk IO" on the Firebase servers.

I put "disk IO" in quotes there, because there are many factors involved here. But in general: *giving the database more nodes to consider, will make it slower*. Or the opposite: *if you give the database less work to do, it will be done with that work faster*.

Comment: >"But to know which children to send it needs to consider all of them."
Frank, are you sure about that? I cannot see it into the docs. If it is true then wondering about limitToFirst+startAt? ..I think firebase should share more on what is the expect time/space/.. complexity of all types of index queries..

Comment: I agree if there was more documentation of the performance of the different types of queries. But I am also sure about the statement you're asking about: considering more data takes more time.

Comment: Frank, I agree with "considering more data takes more time", but it is not the same as "But to know which children to send it needs to consider all of them.", right? I would expect that range queries are efficient using an index in general and efficient means that you do not need to traverse all the elements - it should not be like O(N).